# fputcsv() writing data separated with semicolon in separate cells

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

In my application I'm generating a csv file with some data using php. My code looks like shown below.

```
$fileHandle = fopen('test.csv', "w");
$list = array (
    array('aaa;cc;kk;', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fileHandle, $fields);
}
fclose($fileHandle);
```

The data `aaa;cc;kk;` is written to separate cells (1st cell contains aaa, 2nd cell contains cc) instead of writing it to a single cell.

In the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), it is mentioned that, by default delimiter is comma. Why this values are getting separated with semicolon? How can I avoid that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "separate cells" do you mean how it looks in Excel?  In the plain text CSV how does it look?

Comment: @MattS. I mean how it looks in Excel. In plain text, csv is correct.

Comment: Then the CSV is valid.  This isn't a programming question but an Excel support question. You probably have to configure it to not treat ";" as a delimiter.

Comment: Fields with embedded commas must be enclosed within double-quote characters

Answer (score -2):

The delimiter can be set by using the third parameter of `fputcsv():`

> int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter =
>   "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )

Please change:

```
fputcsv($file,explode(';',$customerInfo));
```

to:

```
fputcsv($file,explode(';',$customerInfo), ";");
```

Please check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) before asking on Stack Overflow.